# flutter : how to bind hive watching into RxList object in getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-hive

I am using hive and getx together, I am trying to get all data inside hive with `watch` method:

```
   Stream<List<VocabularyModel>> watchVocabsFromdb() => hiveService.vocabularyBox
      .watch()
      .map((event) => hiveService.vocabularyBox.values
          .where((element) => element.remember == true)
          .toList());
```

In controller I am using this method:

```
class WordsController extends GetxController {
  WordsController();
  late Stream<List<VocabularyModel>> allVocabs;
  @override
  void onReady() {
    log.info('onReady');
    super.onReady();

    allVocabs = repository.watchVocabsFromdb();
  }
```

Inside view I am using Obx to catch change of hive box :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(() => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: controller.allVocabs.length, ///... Future<int> is not int
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container();
              },
            )),
      ),
```

How can I use hive whats like obs list?

Answer (score 0):

Change `late Stream<List<VocabularyModel>> allVocabs;` to an RxList:

```
final allVocabs = RxList<VocabularyModel>([]);
```

Then on `onInit()` bind your stream to it:

```
allVocabs.bindStream(repository.watchVocabsFromdb());
```

After that you can observe it as usual using `Obx` or `GetX`.

Comment: Nothing is returned . How can I watch all data from box in this method ` watchVocabsFromdb()` @S.M. AHANGIR